# How do I know if PHP is compatible with the OS?

Tags: php, centos

I am on Centos 7.8 and I wanted to know where I can find information (website or others) that will tell me if PHP 7.3 or 7.4 is compatible with my OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not CentOS that is responsible for compatibility, but Apache.

According to [PHP.net](https://wiki.php.net/platforms), All 1.x and 2.x versions of Apache are supported on Linux x86 and amd64. PHP7 doesn't appear to be compatible with Apache 1.x, although there are some hacky ways to make it work, but I wouldn't recommend that. 7.3 and 7.4 are both fully compatible with Apache 2.x.

Comment: ok thx for your reply and for example if i want to know compatibility betwen Centos and Maria DB ? It's Centos responsible or not ?

Comment: Generally, a yum install will grab the latest supported version of whatever you want to install. CentOS is compatible with MariaDB, and in fact, many versions ship with it already preinstalled. CentOS 7 fully supports MariaDB 10.4. I typically just check the installation guides for whatever OS I'm using to find out compatibility. They usually list the latest supported version in there somewhere.